# Python 3 - convert the staircase from right-aligned to LEFT ALIGNED, composed of # symbols and spaces

Tags: python, python-3.x, whitespace

```
sc = []
n = 6
for i in range(n):
    sc.append("#")
    scstr = ''.join(map(str, sc))
    print(scstr)
```

I tried to use the code below to reverse the output by adding padding white spaces but it prints out a distorted staircase.

```
# print(scstr.rjust(n-i, ' '))  -- trying to print reversed staircase
```

Please help convert the staircase from  right-aligned to LEFT ALIGNED, composed of # symbols and spaces.

Attached is a visual description of expected output

[image: Expected Output and my Output]

Comment: How do you want the output to look like

Comment: Write expected output too

Comment: @user1767754  I have just attached expected output vs my output, please check it

Comment: @sachindubey  expected output attached ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "right align" a row by padding it with spaces. Here, the Ith rows should have N-I spaces and I hashes:

```
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    print(' ' * (n  - i) + '#' * i)
```

Comment: this works perfect .. Only thing is the base and heights must be 6 '#'  .. and this prints 5 "#" ..

Comment: @EwuramaMinkaAkuoko yeah, had an off-by-one error in my `range` clause. Edited and fixed.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`str.rjust()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_rjust.htm)

```
for i in range(1,n+1):
    print( ('#'*i).rjust(n))
```

Comment: this also works first answer but it print 5 '#'  instead of 6 '#' ... the base and height of triangle must be equal to n = 6

Answer (score 3):

I like the new string formatting.

**Code:**

```
for i in range(10, -1, -1):
    print("{0:#<10}".format(i*" "))
```

**Produces:**

```
         #
        ##
       ###
      ####
     #####
    ######
   #######
  ########
 #########
##########
```

Comment: I actually wanted to show this one.. otherwise formatting would be nonsense. And yeah `{}` without a 0 isn't pep conform. Pylint will complain.At least its complaining.

Comment: Please, i would appreciate it. I will have to go to bed though. will read it tomorrow! Surprise me :D

Comment: you could pass the padding value in format itself: `print("{0:#<{1}}".format(i*" ",10))` so number isn't hardcoded in format, can be a variable. I'll let you check that, and editing to add parentheses so it's python 3 compliant

Comment: I like this the best tbh.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ as usual OP chooses the least good answer... sob :)

Comment: Ahh...i actually started doing {1} with the second parameter, but as it wasn't dynamically changing i liked it to have static.

Answer (score 0):

replace n with n+1

```
n = 6
for i in range(n+1):
    print(' '*(n-i) + '#' * i)
```